# Flutter, Shared Preferences: Where are the shared preferences stored on the device?

Tags: android, flutter

I use the internal shared preferences to store key/values on an Android device. I wanted to have a look at this data directly using a file explorer but I cannot find where it is stored physically. Most apps have an own directory on Android/data but there is no folder for my Flutter app.

Do you have an idea where the data is stored locally?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** (To make my problem clearer):

I need to access this data from outside app. A user of my app is not able to start the app anymore for some reasons. I want him to send me the internal data for debugging purposes.

So is it possible to fetch the related files in any way without the app self?

Comment: They are stored in a subfolder of Context.getFilesDir() which is private for your app. So other apps have no access. File managers have no access.

Comment: /data/data/<packename>/shared_prefs/

Comment: @blackapps so there's absolutely no way to get access to this data?

Comment: And the file: /data/data/<packename>/shared_prefs/<packagename>_preferences.xml

Comment: Of course you have access. Your app has access. As you know the directory and even the file name you can list the contents of the directory or read the file.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, my problem is, an user is not able to start the app anymore. I want him to send me the internal data for debugging. So I need access from outside the app...

Comment: Android studio can browse the directory.

Comment: @blackapps Android Studio shows me under data/data/my.app/: "run-as: package not debuggable" but not the data unfortunately...

Comment: `I need to access this data from outside app.` I think you are still confusing as it seems that a user of your app (whithout AS) needs access. Far from your home.

Comment: You can ask him to uninstall the app and reinstall it or you can ask the user to understand how he got that issue so that you can replicate it

Comment: Send the user an update that does not read from preferences or does anything except making a copy of the preferences file to external storage.

Comment: Or just update your app to catch more exceptions and display at catch the message in a Toast.

Comment: `I want him to send me the internal data for debugging purposes` - you can get bug report from user using [developer option](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).

Answer (score 3):

On native android its stored inside the data folder. The path will be something like

```
/data/data/<your_package_name>/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml
```

On Flutter projects its stored inside the same folder but with fixed name `FlutterSharedPreferences.xml`
Something like

```
/data/data/<your_package_name>/shared_prefs/FlutterSharedPreferences.xml
```

### Edited in response of updated question - 05/01/2023

If your app is relying heavily on sharedpreferences then I don't think there is a way to get it from outside your app. But I have an idea which you can try.
Try this package `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_logs`.
This can create log files in file system. If your app is currently crashing after opening you can try to put this log code to write down the sharedpreferences inside the log file. Then you can setup some code to send the logs by email.

But there are few catches in this approach.

1. You have to set this code in initial screen like splashscreen and wait until this process is complete.
2. You have to send this updated apk and ask your user to install it.

I suggest you to implement this anyhow as in future you might get stuck in similar situation if you are relying on sharedpreferences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit. I need access to the files from outside the app. Do you know a way (without emulator, since I need a real user do this for me).

Comment: This is not possible in real device. Its a security violation issue. I think it could be happen on rooted android device. But I don't think this is possible for normal users.

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences are stored in an xml file in the app data folder, i.e.

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/
```

You can access these from Device File Explorer Tab inside the Android Studio IDE on the right side :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit. I need access to the files from outside the app. Do you know a way (without emulator, since I need a real user do this for me).

Comment: Isn't possible without root in many devices

Comment: The emulator is irrelevant. You can do this with any device.

Comment: @blackapps changing the system files is not allowed in Android anymore you need to have a rooted device for that

Comment: Android Studio shows me under data/data/my.app/: "run-as: package not debuggable" but not the data unfortunately...

Comment: can you share a screenshot or something

Comment: `changing the system files is not allowed in Android anymore` What do you mean? Any app can write to, read and delete its preferences files.

Comment: @blackapps by the user themselves that is

Comment: The user could never reach those files. So what is it that you try to tell?

Comment: @blackapps that if he wants to update them you need a rooted device